# Ckeditor doesn't appear at foreign countries

Tags: ckeditor

Hello this is my js config file

```
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'detay',
            {


        filebrowserUploadUrl :      "../uploader.php?type=files",
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl : "../uploader.php?type=images",
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : "../uploader.php?type=flash",

        language: 'az',
                // Remove unused plugins.
                removePlugins :'bidi,button,dialogadvtab,div,forms,horizontalrule,iframe,indent,pagebreak,showborders,stylescombo,table,tabletools,templates',
                // Width and height are not supported in the BBCode format, so object resizing is disabled.

                // Define font sizes in percent values.
                fontSize_sizes : "30/30%;50/50%;100/100%;120/120%;150/150%;200/200%;300/300%",
                toolbar :
                [
                    ['Bold', 'Italic','Underline'],
                    ['FontSize'],
                    ['TextColor'],
                    ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'SpecialChar'],
                    ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
                    ['Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
                    ['Source', 'Undo','Redo'],
                    ['Maximize']
                ],

        } );
```

And this is HTML:

```
  <label for="detay"></label>
  <textarea id="noise" name="detay"></textarea>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ckayar.js"></script>
```

it is working for my country (TURKEY) but in other countries (except TUrkey) this code doesnt work , Text area doesnt show. 
What can i do for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "az" language in CKEditor, so it's reverting to detection of the user's language and I would bet that you have removed all the lang files except Turkish, so it doesn't find the lang file and you get an error in the browser console.